# wrong date when i change int time with FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: date, datetime

I have a old database that i want to transfer, but i have some trouble with my column `dateP(int)`.  I got a wrong datetime.

In my old script, I enter the date-time like this:

```
$date_created = time();
$data_insert = "INSERT TO table $date_created, $title";
```

Now I have the column `datePub (int)` that I convert to time stamp format,

For resolve this problem i make this.

```
UPDATE `table ` SET `date_created` = FROM_UNIXTIME(`datePub `)
```

But I got a wrong date when I make this `date('M d, Y', $PuDate);`

Comment: It is always necessary to add a language tag when you ask something related to your code. Please [edit] to do so now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put the right specifier in date_format and its good now.

Comment: While it's perfectly acceptable to self-answer, it'd be better if you could flesh out your answer a bit (for example, what *is* the right specifier) so it'll be a bit more helpful for any future readers of this question. (also, uh, could you include a tag for whatever programming language you're using?)